# How can I sort my CSV data from going into from rows into columns based on the header titles

Tags: python, csv, header, title

After working with Python and the CSV module for a while, I finally was able to extract some data with specific values after transposing the original output, and we plan on using the code for future reports. Thing is, the code needs to read it in columns, not in rows, for the report.

Essentially, the data is like this: `1/Location/Ratio/Delay/Grade`, then `3/Location/Ratio/Delay/Grade`, etc. until the data ends.

Below each of them, is specific data related to to them. Basically, the output is reading in a giant pool of rows, and I want to essentially have the data read like this:

```
1/Location/Ratio/Delay/Grade
(Data)
```

But for all of the data. Instead of a long row, I basically was looking at a code snippet that'll allow me to separate the rows by columns based on the numbers given at each spot. (E.g, 1, 3, 8, 22, etc...) This will allow me to have a big row. Without having to transpose, because I already did that to get this far.

Thank you guys in advance! If I have to post my codes, I'm willing to do so.

I want it to go from this...
[image]

...to this
[image]

Comment: Your question would benefit from having a fully worked example showing say 10 lines of input, and your expected output. At the moment it is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve (press the edit button to add more content).

Comment: My apologies. I'm still learning this site. I've added some pictures to explain what's going on in the csv files I'm converting.

Comment: I was reading up on a melt function through the Pandas module, but I've not a clue on how to start that in this function. Is anyone well versed in this area?

Comment: I did have a look at your updated question, and it still is not obvious what you are trying to achieve, even with the pictures.

Comment: Basically, the titles are repeating in each section. First in the row is a number, then the variables I pulled (Movement, v/c Ratio, Delay(s), etc.) then another number, same variables, and so on. Each number starts off a new section of data. I want to have it so that the data, with the headers(Variable names and number intact) are not next to each other, but rather stacked upon each other in a column. I want the headers to start from the number to the Intersection Capactiy Utilization for each section, and repeat that for each section of data represented by the numbers (1, 3, 7, 11 Etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will give you some ideas, the following script takes an input CSV file and determines how many horizontal blocks there are by counting how many columns contain the word `Movement`.

It then splits each group of columns at each `Movement` column and write the output to a new `output.csv` file.

```
from itertools import product

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    rows = list(csv_input)  # Load all rows in
    block_count = len([x for x in rows[0] if x.find('Movement') != -1])
    row_count = len(rows)
    col_count = len(rows[0]) / block_count

    for block, row in product(range(block_count), range(row_count)):
        csv_output.writerow(rows[row][block * col_count : block * col_count + col_count])
```

So the following input file:

```
1 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,2 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,3 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Would produce the following output file:

```
1 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
2 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
3 Movement,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9

Comment: It throws up the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aobryant/Desktop/Yep.py", line 8, in <module>
    rows = list(csv_input)  # Load all rows in
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: Are you using Python 3.x?